# Deleting inherited dict elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, destructor

I have a dict of Objects which are to be destroyed as follows.

```
class Elem:
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
    .
    .
    def __del__(self):
       print('destroying elem' + self.name)

class DerivedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
       super(DerivedDict, self).__init__()

    def __del__():
        for k in self.keys():
            del self[k]


elem = Elem('myname')
ddict = DerivedDict()
ddict['myname'] = elem

# this line should delete the both the elem the entry in ddict.
del ddict
```

When try this I am geting this error

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: I get this error, it may be a version related difference because in Python 3 they made changes to `dict.keys()`

Comment: @Exellan: this the exact example I am trying. the python version I am using 3.4.3

Comment: Do you really need explicit destructors in either of these classes? `del ddict` using the default destructor will clean up `ddict` and its elements, assuming there are no other references to those elements.

Comment: I would to print something to the log, when those items are deleted. is there anyother way to do that, without using explicit destructors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python 3.x and the "keys" method gives you a live view of the dictionary keys. When these change, due to you deleting items, Python can't consistently continue iterating over them.

To fix it, just pass your call to `self.keys` to the `list` constructor: therefore you get a list with a snapshot of the existing keys prior to the iteration:

```
def __del__():
    for k in list(self.keys()):
        del self[k]
```

Now, there are some tricks here and there for proper subclassing a dict that might take you by surprise. If the only behavior you want is to explictly delete your elements on dict deletion, there is no need for that at all - otherwise, see the docs about collection.UserDict - which makes subclassing easier, or collections.abc.MutableSequence - both will warrant you full dict behavior with the need to override a minimum set of methods.

One other note: it is not considered good practice in Python to rely on `__del__` to actually be run when your objects go out of scope: there might be other references to them, and them `del self.key[x]` simply **won't** call the `__del__` method on the object. And during interpreter shutdown (At the end of your program), there is no guarantee at all `__del__` will be called even for objects that correctly are no longer referenced.

You'd better add a explicit `delete` (not special `__del__` ) method and call it instead of relying on the `del` statement mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to delete item while iterating. Actually I don't see there is any need to override `__del__`. Simply using:

```
class DerivedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
       super(DerivedDict, self).__init__()
```

This will also cause `__del__` of `Elem` being called.

Comment: *shame on me - I just edited your question when I went up to edit mine to include the side notes about `__del__`. I've rolled it back now.

Comment: That's OK. You answer is accepted, after all. Congrats.